# Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova

I am building a website with the use of phonegap. I ve noticed that bakcbone and jquery -jqm, don't work in the compiled application. Actually, I am receiving in eclipse the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/JSscript.js:7

Also I am receiving the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/JSscript.js:4484

And my touch and click event doesn't function in the extraxted app. Any idea how can I fix this??

JS order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src='./scripts/JSscript.js'></script>
```

And JSscript:

```
var obj;
var profile;    

$(function() {

    // Backbone model Creation
    var ProfileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
                tstamp: 'adffdsa',
                map:"",
                tagsCloud:"",
                sentiment: "",
                usersCloud: "",
                timeline: "",
                highlights: "",
                signals: ""
        },

        initialize: function() {

        }

    });

    //Backbone model initialization
    profile = new ProfileModel({
                tstamp: 'adffdsa',
                map:"",
                tagsCloud:"",
                sentiment: "",
                usersCloud: "",
                timeline: "",
                highlights: "",
                signals: ""
    });

    var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

                    model: ProfileModel,
                    url: 'data.php'
    });   

    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#profiles",
        template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
        render: function(eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
        //push data to obj for map script
        obj = profile.toJSON();
        // Add data to DOM element
        $(this.el).html(profileTemplate);
        }, this);

            return this;

        }


    });

        var profiles = new ProfileList([profile]);    
        var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});

        // Fetching data from server every n seconds
        setInterval(function() {

                profiles.fetch({reset: true});

        }, 4000); // Time in milliseconds

         profiles.bind('reset', function () {

                profilesView.render();

        });
```

});

Comment: Are you sure your Backbone file is higher in the DOM than `JSscript.js`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add cordoca.js and phonegap.js but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you share JSscript.js so that we can see what is wrong?

Comment: Inside .js file i try to connect with a server. Is there a chance that a call to a php file may cause those problems?? Furthermore I ve got another .js file which contains jquery and jqm script for animate DOM elements. It doesn't work either.

Comment: I define backbone and underscore.js locally but nothing change. I ve got the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found out that external url have to be defined in config.xml with . Thus,  animation.js works like a charm. However, I cant find why backbone.je doesnt work. It seems that data.php is causing problems.

```
 var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

                    model: ProfileModel,
                    url: 'data.php'
    });
```

I am receiving Unknown chromium error: 0. File data.php location is on localhost, so I add in 
config.xml ip adress. However I am still receiving chromuim error. Any idea?